# SSIS package fails while running using cmd line

Tags: sql-server, cmd, ssis, etl

when I try to run a SSIS package , it fails throwing an error

> Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or higher.

this occurs only with a few packages, few of them succeed while few of them fail with this error. I am confused, can someone help me on this ?

All the packages are the same, i am creating a ADO.net source and OLE DB destination which dumps the file to sql server 2012.

please advice.

Comment: The error says clearly what you need? `To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or higher.`

Comment: there are the other packages which are running successfully on the same machine. it is only with a few packages that throws out this error.

Comment: Which Windows version are you running? And, is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio.

Go To Projects Menu -> Package Properties ->Debugging

Change `Run64BitRuntime` to `false`

[image: Menu]

[image]

Comment: I changed the runtime to false as you posted , but it throws out the same error.

Comment: please refer to *"Installation Considerations for dtexec (SSIS Tool) on 64-bit Computers"* in this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx